# Sass problem: >sass --watch style.scss:style.css invalid option: --watch

Tags: sass

When I run:

> sass --watch style.scss:style.css

gives me

invalid option: --watch

why?
this is good:

> sass -v

gives me:

Haml/Sass 2.2.24 (Powerful Penny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Sass 3 in order to use --watch